# Should categorical data be normalised in linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, categorical-data, normalization

I have data similar to the following:

```
[
   [0, 4, 15]
   [0, 3, 7]
   [1, 5, 9]
   [2, 4, 15]
]
```

I used One Hot Encoder to preprocess this data so it is suitable for linear regression to give me this:

```
[
   [1, 0, 0, 4, 15]
   [1, 0, 0, 3, 7]
   [0, 1, 0, 5, 9]
   [0, 0, 1, 4, 15]
]
```

However, I then wish to normalise this data.

Should I normalise category data?

Comment: I'd simply use categorical / dummy variables. Not sure what the distance between samples on the categorical feature "axis" could mean in an Euclidean metric.

Comment: Why do you want to normalize or standardize?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [whether to rescale indicator / binary / dummy predictors for LASSO](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69568/whether-to-rescale-indicator-binary-dummy-predictors-for-lasso)

Comment: Please give more details of what your data are.