# Do we need to scale the encoded data also?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-scaling

I have a dataset with both categorical and numerical values. First I encoded the categorical data using one-hot encoding. Then the next step is to feature scaling. For that, I am going to use standardizing. But I have a doubt did I want to scale the encoded values also? Or did I want to encode only the numerical value?

Comment: also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/69568/232706, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/31652/55122, and several Related questions from those.