# Standardize continuous predictor variables on [0, 1] scale?

Tags: multiple-regression, lasso, standardization

I'm working on a health care regression model predicting # of inpatient visits. My analysis dataset includes a number of hybrid continuous/categorical predictor variables which can hold values on a 0 to 1 scale, inclusive. The variables are measuring the proportion of hospital inpatient visits for which a particular diagnosis category were reported (so if 5 out of 10 visits were due to asthma for a particular patient, then the asthma variable = 0.5).

I'm using the glmnet package in R to run a penalized lasso regression. Should I standardize the [0, 1] predictor variables? Technically they are continuous variables, however I'm worried that the upper and lower limits may make interpretation difficult if I standardize.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a link given [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68077/are-categorical-variables-standardized-differently-in-penalized-regression) that may be helpful.